# Cómo conectar con multiples bases de datos en asp .net core 2

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Hola tengo el siguiente problema, recién inicié un proyecto en ASP .NET Core 2
todo iba bien hasta que empezaron las conexiones a base de datos. cuando es una sola netcore lo hace de maravilla, pero según la arquitectura se emplea una base de datos principal y una segunda que cambia según el cliente, por lo que en la primera tenemos el cliente y la base de datos a la que apunta y de ahí la base de datos va a cambiar dinamicamente según el cliente. En PHP como es bien sabido tiene muchas libertades y el proyecto actualmente realiza esta tarea sin inconvenientes.

Se puede llegar a modificar el appsetting.json de esa forma o algo por el estilo?

Buscando encontré lo siguiente pero realmente no entiendo muy bien cómo implementarlo:
[Get Multiple Connection Strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37287427/get-multiple-connection-strings-in-appsettings-json-without-ef)

Comment: Por lo que puedo llegar a entender, ¿el problema que tienes es que no consigues recuperar de appsetting.json esa segunda connectionstring? No me queda muy claro.

Comment: No, necesito conectarme a varias bases de datos según se vaya necesitando, es decir, según el usuario que yo tenga se va a conectar a X o Y base de datos

Comment: No consigo ver cual es la dificultad. Por favor, añade el código que te da problemas para poder trabajar sobre algo.

Comment: Esto te generara un modelo con lastablas de la base de datos que elijas y solo lo ejecutas para cada conexion Scaffold-DbContext "Server=nombreDelServidor,1433;Initial Catalog=nombreDeLaBD;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=xxxxxx;Password=xxxxxxx;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Model/DB -Context nombreDelContexto-t pon las tablas a importarseparadas por una coma -f

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Con entity framework en netcore 2 podés crear por lo que yo sé y he podido probar la cantidad que quieras de DbContext, 
cada uno tiene su propia connection string y sus propias tablas, lo cual te permite conectarte a diferendes DB

(Lo de abajo es un DbContext, podés crear más y son cada uno una base de datos diferente)

```
public class Db : DbContext
{
 public DbSet<Localidades> Localidades { get; set; }
 public DbSet<Usuario> Usuario{get;set;}

 protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder 
 optionsBuilder)
 {
     optionsBuilder.UseMySQL("server=179.43.XXX.X;database=XXXXX;");
 }

 protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
 {
   base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

   modelBuilder.Entity<Localidades>(entity =>
   {
     entity.HasKey(e => e.Id_localidad);
   });
   modelBuilder.Entity<Usuario>(s => s.HasKey(
     e=> e.Id_usuario
   ));
 }
}
```

Comment: Hola Gianluca, creo que sí, sería combinar en cierta forma el método que muestras que efectivamente ya lo había visto con algun a variable de entorno para tomar el nombre de la DB y complementar la string con dicha variable

Answer (score 0):

¿Por qué la conexión a la base de datos desde la capa de presentación?

Estos problemas - y parecidos -, son producto por no respetar funcionalmente las capas `ASP.NET`, incluyendo `Core`; debe dedicarse única y exclusivamente de presentar o representar *(lo que la capa de negocio le indica)* y la del negocio interactuar con la capa de datos.

Cualquier solución que apliques manteniendo esa equivocada forma de diseñar, donde desde la capa de presentación hace una **conexión** a la base de datos, se mantendrá, o aplicarás un parche; pero, en el fondo, será una bomba de tiempo esa solución.

**Recomendación**:

Da un paso atrás para para dar dos adelante. Rediseña tu arquitectura, pon las cosas en su lugar, y verás que todo te irá mucho mejor.

Comment: Efectivamente, se planteó realizar una base de datos multi teniente para solucionar este problema de diseño ya que a la larga efectivamente puede ocasionar muchos problemas

Answer (score 0):

Puedes crear 2 clases diferentes de Contexto.

La primera, tal como estas usando ahora en donde se conecta a la bd de la aplicación con toda la configuración y demás.

La segunda clase de contexto, puedes crearla en base al código de respuesta de Gianluca Fiore agregando un parametro en el constructor con el connectionString y luego en la función `OnConfiguring` user ese valor para realizar la conexión.

De esta manera, puedes seguir utilizando IOC para la referencia a la BD de la aplicación y para cada cliente creas el BDContext especifico (te recomiendo que implementes algún patron factory para obtener el contexto configurado para el cliente en particular para tener la lógica de configuración e instanciación en un solo lugar y facilitar los cambios a futuro)